# XML Error while Modifying Sales Order in QB Desktop

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I am trying to modify a sales order created in QB Desktop. But it gives me XML error

```
0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream
```

Here is my XML Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <SalesOrderModRq>
      <SalesOrderMod>
        <TxnID>1-1672737866</TxnID>
        <EditSequence>1672737866</EditSequence>
        <CustomerRef>
          <FullName>156004 Loose Bee Ln</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <TxnDate>2023-01-03</TxnDate>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>123</Addr1>
          <Addr2></Addr2>
          <City>Gity</City>
          <State>Ritham</State>
          <PostalCode>5555</PostalCode>
          <Country>Universe</Country>
        </BillAddress>
        <PONumber>4444444</PONumber>
        <Other>Southshore Bay</Other>
        <SalesOrderLineMod>
         <TxnID>3-1672737866</TxnID
          <ItemRef>
            <FullName>Single Family - One Story</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>Foundation</Desc>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Amount>85.00</Amount>
          <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>Lot</DataExtName>
            <DataExtValue>8/98</DataExtValue>
          </DataExtMod>
          <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>Address</DataExtName>
            <DataExtValue>156004 Loose Bee Ln</DataExtValue>
          </DataExtMod>
        </SalesOrderLineMod>
      </SalesOrderMod>
    </SalesOrderModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get this error:

`0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream`

It means you used an XML tag incorrectly, an unsupported XML tag, or an XML tag in the wrong order.

You can refer to the documentation to see what supported tags, their order, etc. are:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/salesordermod

At least at first glance, I can see that `TxnID` inside `SalesOrderLineMod` is not correct (maybe you meant `TxnLineID` instead?):

```
      <SalesOrderLineMod>
         <TxnID>3-1672737866</TxnID
```

It may also be worth double-checking those `DataExtMod` tags too.

Comment: Thanks @Keith Palmer Jr., The error fixed, even syntax error and xml  error also was there ( actually I have to use TxnLineID instead of TxnID), But when I tried with DataExtMod it gives error,. Wthout DataExt XML SO modifications works. But from the above documentation too, I'm troubling to find out exact modify structure for Data Ext. Can you help on that?

Comment: You probably want to do a separate `DataExtMod` request, separate from your `SalesOrderAdd` request.

Comment: @ Keith Palmer Jr. Can I pass both 'SalesOrderMod' ans 'DataExtMod' in same  XML request? Or I have to sent two XML structure as separate request? Can you give a sample example for that.

Comment: You can do it in a single request. There's some examples of other folks doing this if you search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=qbxml+multiple+requests